# Neo4jClient - Create index from within Neo4jClient?

Tags: neo4jclient

Is there a way to create an index from within Neo4jClient? I've done a raw query, but don't think that's the best option.  My reason for doing so is in testing purposes where I need to drop/recreate databases to test performance of different designs.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do indexes like:

```
graphClient.Cypher
    .Create("INDEX ON :Label(Property)")
    .ExecuteWithoutResults();
```

and constraints like:

```
graphClient.Cypher
    .CreateUniqueConstraint("identity", "property")
    .ExecuteWithoutResults();
```

(originally from [How to Create a Node with Neo4jClient in Neo4j v2?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19534511/how-to-create-a-node-with-neo4jclient-in-neo4j-v2))

Comment: Thanks! Hadn't thought about using the same Create() method.