# Neo4JClient Create Unique Constraint

Tags: c#, neo4jclient

I am trying to create unique constrain using accepted answer found at: [Neo4jClient - Create index from within Neo4jClient?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21556792/neo4jclient-create-index-from-within-neo4jclient)

I am using Neo4jClient v1.1.0.11

The example is:

```
graphClient.Cypher
    .CreateUniqueConstraint("identity", "property")
    .ExecuteWithoutResults();
```

The problem is that when I execute this example I receive this exception:

> SyntaxException: Invalid input ')': expected an identifier character, whitespace or NodeLabel (line 1, column 31 (offset: 30))
>   "CREATE CONSTRAINT ON (identity) ASSERT property IS UNIQUE"
>                                  ^

When I use this statement:

```
client.Cypher
    .Create("CREATE CONSTRAINT ON (c:User)ASSERT c.UserId IS UNIQUE")
    .ExecuteWithoutResults();
```

I receive this error:

> SyntaxException: Invalid input 'O': expected 'r/R' (line 1, column 16 (offset: 15))
>   "CREATE CREATE CONSTRAINT ON (c:User)ASSERT c.UserId IS UNIQUE"
>                   ^

My question is what is the correct way of creating unique index using Neo4JClient? An example would be appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In your first code snippet you are not specifying what you are trying to create the constraint on. Add the identifier, label and property as follows

```
graphClient.Cypher
    .CreateUniqueConstraint("c:User", "c.UserId")
    .ExecuteWithoutResults();
```

Your second snippet is merely adding create twice. Maybe this could be fixed like so

```
graphClient.Cypher
    .Create("CONSTRAINT ON (c:User) ASSERT c.UserId IS UNIQUE")
    .ExecuteWithoutResults();
```

Although I would recommend the first approach...

Comment: Additional question: Can you please tell the C# way of this statement: client.Cypher.Create("INDEX ON :User(FullName)").ExecuteWithoutResults();

Comment: @huber.duber That's the way I'd go about doing it, there's no specific entry point for creating indexes as there is for unique constraint. If you want it - feel free to add as an issue on the `Neo4jClient` github page, and I can look into it - or you could do a pull request if you want - all are gladly accepted :)

Comment: Thanks, will try that